# TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'numpy.dtype'> in write()

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, python-applymap

So i am reading a .xlsx file and i need to check how many variables in the xlsx file belong to each datatype in pandas and finally export it to excel.

So here is the code :

```
sheet = pd.read_excel(r"D:\Users\850034535\AnacondaProjects\Jupyter Project\Sample.xlsx",sheetname=2)
alldtypes = sheet.dtypes.value_counts()
alldtypes_df = list_of_all_variables.to_frame()
alldtypes_df.to_excel('123.xlsx')
```

This code gives an error: " TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'numpy.dtype' "

So then i converted the dataframe to str type, so now an additional line of code was added :

```
 alldtypes_df = alldtypes_df.applymap(str)
```

But still it is showing me the same error and the error given in the title.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems need convert index to `string`s:

```
alldtypes_df.index = alldtypes_df.index.astype(str)
```

Comment: Worked Flawlessly, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @explorer_x - Glad can help!